# random string generator with each lines different color

Tags: php

I'm trying to create in PHP a randomized string script, but complex, because each line must have a different color, the color is not important, it can be random, but should not be the same twice.
The output must be something like this :

```
Hello#in blue color
Hello#in red color
Hello#in pink color
```

i've tried with the `str_repeat` function,

```
echo "Colored random String Generator";
echo "<br>";
echo str_repeat("Hello <br>", 100);
```

but there are too few parameters, i can't really put a `<span style="color:$randomColor>` between them

Did i miss something ?

Comment: Start with an array of colors. Then shuffle it (google "php shuffle array"). Now use array_map to turn the color into the <span>. Now output all array elements.

Comment: Random is subjective, how is your script known to pick what color? where is that defined?

Comment: Would a `for` loop not be better? You can't change the value of the string in str_repeat after the initial value is set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to tweak the random color generator as I chucked it together but this is basically what you are after I believe:

```
function randomColor() {
    return str_pad(dechex(rand(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF)), 6, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

echo "Colored random String Generator<br>";

$repeatCount = 100;

for ($x = 0; $x <= $repeatCount; $x++) {
  echo "<span style=\"color: #".randomColor().";\">Hello</span> <br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !
You saved my grade tomorrow

Answer (score -1):

Try like this :

echo str_repeat("<span style="color:".$randomColor.">Hello 
", 100);

Mark it as solved if this helps or post your entire code in the comments.

Comment: What generates the random color? If you test your answer, you will see that str_repeat doesn't allow for changing values and will just repeat the initial value

Comment: Your answer would look better if it was formatted using the format controls. Use four spaces before a line of code to create a code block, and two backticks before and after an item that you want to embed in your text. I hope this helps.